# Can't use some buttons on my keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I have a probem wih my keyboard on my computer. some day ago the <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>backspace</kbd> buttons have stopped working, but today the <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>  <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>é</kbd> <kbd>right shift</kbd> buttons too.

Today when I turned on my computer it showed me the stucked key dialogbox. Press ok (I think I should press no), and after sign in I noticed  <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>  <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>é</kbd> <kbd>right shift</kbd> buttons don't working neither.

Is my keyboard went wrong?

Comment: these are the buttons which are not working.

Comment: This probably means your shift key is stuck... Did you try to ensure it's not depressed / stuck down? What happens if you press shift 5 times in a row?

Comment: Nothing happens, but, shift seems working (left) as I can write capitalized.

Comment: Do you use any keyboard mapping tools? Do you get that message (About sticky keys) every time you turn on your PC? Best thing to do is try a new keyboard, they've only cheap

Comment: No, and no, I have seen it only two times yet. (In time with the first buttons went wrong)

Comment: Borrow another keyboard to test it is the only thing I can suggest at the moment

Comment: I'm guessing you spilled something on the keyboard a few days ago.  If it was a cola soft drink then the keyboard's toast.